# Interface builder is defaulting to Helvetica just now

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder

I have been using a specific font which I've been testing on the iPad directly and it was working fine.
Now all of a sudden, the label or textview using the font are default back to Helvetica.
As a hack I'm setting the font manually, but this is ridiculous

```
self.taskNameView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BradleyHandITCTT-Bold" size:24.0];
```

Any idea why all of a sudden, interface builder is freaking out?
I've tried cleaning but that didn't help.

I'm on XCode 4 and working on iOS 4.3

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to override all fonts in your application, maybe a category on UIFont will do the trick?
Try adding this to e.g. your AppDelegate.m:

```
@implementation UIFont (FontOverride)
+(UIFont*) systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"radleyHandITCTT-Normal" size:fontSize];
}    
+(UIFont*) boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"radleyHandITCTT-Bold" size:fontSize];
}

+(UIFont*) italicSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"radleyHandITCTT-Italic" size:fontSize];
}
@end
```